# Чем отличается VPS/VDS от хостинга?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер

И что из этого дешевле, чтоб разместить свой сайт в интернете?
Один человек говорит, что при деплое нужно платить один раз только за доменное имя своего сайта. Другой человек говорит, что нужно платить ежемесячно небольшую сумму.

Comment: хостинг и доменное имя две совершенно разные вещи и совершенно разные услуги. домен оплачивается раз в год, хостинг ежемесячно. домен это просто имя в зоне ни к чему непривязанное. хостинг это размещение своих ресурсов и приложений на сервере. вы можете просто домен оплатить и разместить все что нужно на своей машине, но для этого вам нужен статический IP адрес. Это как правило отдельная услуга у провайдера - стоит рублей 100-150 в месяц. Но если уж тратиться так лучше на хостинг. Постоянно работающая машина в квартире то еще удовольствие

Comment: @МихаилРебров сплю в одной комнате с постоянно работающей машиной, мне норм)

Comment: @andreymal везучий, у меня как новые вентиляторы куплю - так через 3 месяца уже тарахтеть начинают.

Comment: @andreymal, у меня тоже постоянно что-то работает и мне самому тоже норм... но не все с этим согласны и мне периодически за это прилетает)))) поэтому и говорю)

Comment: @МихаилРебров, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря что значит дешевле. Арендовать свой VPS теоретически дешевле, но его нужно настраивать, администрировать, вопрос кто это будет делать? Вы, или системный администратор, которого вы наймёте? Так-же необходимо ПО для работы сайта, движок, БД, и что ещё там есть...

Готовый хостинг арендовать как правило дороже, и возможности ограничены, на свой VPS/VDS можно поставить что угодно, любой софт, который туда влезет. А на готовый хостинг выбор небольшой, НО, администрирование ОС (к которой у вас нет доступа) уже включено, возможности администрирования софта для сайта вами тоже ограничено, это как плюс так и минус, зато не нужно бояться что вы что-то сломаете. Максимум что вы можете сломать - это лично ваш сайт и лично вашу БД.

PS За всё всегда надо платить, вы будете платить за VPS/VDS или хостинг в любом случае, в зависимости от сложности вам могут понадобиться услуги системного администратора, администратора БД, web-программиста. Так-же аренду доменного имени тоже нужно будет оплачивать и продлевать. Если VPS/VDS и хостинг арендуют на месяц, то доменное имя обычно берут минимум на год, крупные организации могут вообще купить лет на 10-20 и "забыть".

Если вы сами начинаете заниматься разработкой сайта, и навыков администрирования у вас нет или очень мало, то после того как вы протестировали сайт локально - оплачивайте доменное имя и выбирайте простенький хостинг, который поддерживает технологию, на которой написан сайт, оплачивайте и заливайте туда, техподдержка вам должна помочь при возникновении проблем, по крайней мере, как минимум, инструкцию вам предоставят.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Всё же больше склоняюсь к VPS/VDS. Хочу научиться администрировать свой сайт. Будет на чём потренироваться. Большинство знакомых советовали хостинг. Но один человек, который очень хорошо разбирается в веб-разработке советует VPS. Надо не делать так как большинство, а делать так, как советуют компетентные люди...

Comment: @Muriam хостинг новичкам предпочтительнее, т.к. вы можете напортачить с настройкой своего сервера и даже этого не заметить, а глядя на хостинг уже будет представление как лучше и "правильней" настраивать. А потом, через месяц уже и vps. Но если вы уже перекурили тонну мануалов как правильно всё настраивать и защищать свой сервер - то вам видней, ибо vps крякают только так...

Comment: если всю жизнь делать то, что предпочитают новички, есть высокая вероятность так и остаться новичком. А умение настраивать vps дает конкурентное преимущество.

Comment: @Muriam настройка серверов - это из другой области. Выполняя двойную работу - вы никому лучше не делаете, ни себе, ни, так сказать, коллегам. Достаточно углубиться в 2 области, чтобы стать экспертом в обеих, всё равно не получится, вы не получите двойной оклад, в лучшем случае х1.2, в то время как более скиловый программист или админ, ставший экспертом, будет и балду пинать (в сравнении с универсалом, который будет двойную работу выполнять и должен будет актуальные знания поддерживать сразу в 2х областях), и х2 получать, т.к. в случае чего критический косяк пофиксить сможет только он...

Comment: Но, мне кажется, как-раз бэкенд разработчик должен уметь настраивать то, о чем мы спорим. Бэкенд - это как-раз то, куда я хочу. А всё остальное - это много лишнего, которое диктует универ.

Comment: Кроме того, никто не мешает новичку стать профи и обогнать конкурентов. Хотя, мешают те же конкуренты. Но, новички развиваются.