# Выбор хостинга для тг бота

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, сервер, хостинг

Всем привет! Я всегда занимался разработкой, но никогда не хостил свои проекты.

Есть тг-бот с базой данных. Пользоваться ботом будут постоянно и подключение однозначно должно быть непрерывным, также бот не маленький и будет расширяться. Пересмотрел и перечитал кучу видео и статей, и не смог найти пример, где размещают на сервер тг-бота, работающего с бд.

Вопросы:

1. База данных должна быть на другом сервере или на том же, где и размещен бот?
2. Если бд все же должна висеть на том же сервере, где и бот, то что мне следует установить на сервер для работы бота с бд?
3. Какую услугу лучше выбрать для бота? (там есть облачный сервер, физический сервер, слышал что-то про VDS и VPS)
4. Какой хостинг мне лучше выбрать для моего проекта? (я слышал про: timeweb.cloud, timeweb, heroku, hostman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> База данных должна быть на другом сервере или на том же, где и размещен бот?

Тебе никто не мешает разместить базу данных использовать на другом сервера (можно взять DBaaS, например), но, если проводить аналогию... с холодильником. Логичнее же его разместить в том же доме, где есть кухня и достаточно места *:)*

> Если бд все же должна висеть на том же сервере, где и бот, то что мне следует установить на сервер для работы бота с бд?

Специфичный вопрос. Зависит от бд, обычно специальный сервер-приложение для этого. Иногда ничего не надо (sqlite например).

> Какую услугу лучше выбрать для бота? (там есть облачный сервер, физический сервер, слышал что-то про VDS и VPS)

Большой вопрос, с этим не подскажу. Думаю [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1331575/418625) немного поможет разобраться.

> Какой хостинг мне лучше выбрать для моего проекта? (я слышал про: timeweb.cloud, timeweb, heroku, hostman)

На этот вопрос невозможно дать ответ, всё зависит от предпочтений и от размера кошелька. В интернете полно обзоров и сравнений, думаю они тоже помогут разобраться.